# RS232 and realterm communication problem

Tags: rs232, 8051

I am not seeing anything on a port in realterm though it is properly sending the data through the port. Anyone run into a similar situation? What am I doing wrong?

I am using a C8051F120 developers kit, a RS232 to USB converter, and realterm.
On the 8051 I have an example program running that mirrors input received on the input.
I have seen the data received then sent on the DB-9 end of the converter using an o-scope, but I haven't seen anything show up on realterm. The converter was working for a different project so it should be good.

Comment: For an initial test you could try shorting pins 2 & 3 on the RS232-USB adapter to make sure things echo back (and stop when you remove the wire).

Comment: I tried that too not knowing if it'd work, but still didn't get anything in realterm.

Comment: That makes it sound like it's a USB adapter problem unless hardware flow control is enabled in RealTerm. Maybe check under device manager the COM port number hasn't changed, maybe force it to a new number and try a few things like that.

Comment: It looks like you have to reset your computer after plugging in a RS232 to USB converter and installing the driver for the first time. BTW, Thanks for your help Peter!

Comment: Add your comment as an answer to your own question. It might be useful to other people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is to reset your computer because the RS232 to USB converter's driver automatically installed needs a restart even though there was no prompt for one before it can be used.